# I keep getting this error on python on codeacademy

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, error-handling, typeerror

I keep getting the error:

```
line 16, in <module> gradebook.remove[2](85)
type error: 'built_in_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong... can anyone please help me. My code is as below:

```
last_semester_gradebook = [["politics", 80], ["latin", 96], ["dance", 97], ["architecture", 65]]

# Your code below: 
subjects = ["physics", "calculus", "poetry", "history"] #grades grades = [98, 97, 85, 88]

gradebook = [["physics", 98], ["calculus", 97], ["poetry", 85], ["history", 88]] print(gradebook) gradebook.append(["computer science", 100]) gradebook.append(["visual arts", 93]) print(gradebook)

gradebook[-1][-1] = 98

gradebook.remove2

gradebook.append4

full_gradebook = last_semester_gradebook + gradebook

print(full_gradebook)
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to include the actual code that produce the error. Lines like `gradebook.remove2` and `
gradebook.append4` will raise `NameError`.

Comment: Also, don't abuse tags - don't add both `python-3.x` and `python-2.7` tags.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
gradebook.remove[2]
```

does not remove the third item from the list.

```
gradebook.pop(2)
```

will remove the third item

Comment: Okay thank you!, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax of the remove() and append() methods:

```
List_name.remove(item)
List_name.append(item)
```

It means you have to use items inside the parentheses.
So your code needs to be like this

```
last_semester_gradebook = [["politics", 80], ["latin", 96], ["dance", 97], ["architecture", 65]]

# Your code below: 
subjects = ["physics", "calculus", "poetry", "history"] #grades 
grades = [98, 97, 85, 88]
gradebook = [["physics", 98], ["calculus", 97], ["poetry", 85], ["history", 88]]
print(gradebook) 

gradebook.append(["computer science", 100]) 
gradebook.append(["visual arts", 93])
print(gradebook)

gradebook[-1][-1] = 98
gradebook.remove(gradebook[2])
gradebook.append(gradebook[4])
full_gradebook = last_semester_gradebook + gradebook
print(full_gradebook)
```